# Parallel Processing Won't Return From Await

Tags: .net, vb.net, async-await

I have some .net code that is using Async and Task.Run() to perform parallel processing.

This issue I have is understanding why it won't return from an Await Task.WhenAll(task) method.

Here is the code where I set up the tasks:

---

```
Dim tasks As New List(Of Task(Of String))
  For Each child As TreeViewNodeData In tv_node_data.Children
       '*Find Tooltip (This will run the validation for the child)*

        tasks.Add(Task.Run(Function() FindTooltip(child)))
  Next

Dim results As String() = Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
```

---

Here is the method that is called by the task.

---

```
Private Function FindTooltip(child As TreeViewNodeData) As String
        Try
            Dim tip As String = child.Feature?.Tooltip 
            Return tip ' <== when stepping through, I can see that the tooltip is outputted as expected
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
            Return String.Empty
        End Try
    End Function
```

---

The issue is likely related to the Tooltip method. As it does some internal processing and calls validation routines. Its the results of the validation that makes up the body of the tooltip.
When I substitute the child.Feature?.Tooltip method and instead just return a string, "My Tooltip" from the FindTooltip method, then it works as expected.

The mystery for me is that when I step through the FindToolTip method I can see that the actual tooltip is generated as expected. 
The line in the method that says, 'Return tip' I can see that the string variable 'tip' is populated with some string that is appropriate and what I expect it to return.

However, when I continue stepping through and it returns to the calling method, it won't step past the

```
Dim results As String() = Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
```

line of code. Instead, it just freezes on that line and refuses to move forward.

This doesn't make sense to me as I know the tasks have already fired and it has returned a string. So why not just complete the routine and complete the Await method?

I've used a similar 'Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)' routines in other parts of my code without issue.

I would understand some type of racing issue, however, I have stepped through the task and I know it has executed and returned a string. So why won't it finish?

Can anyone help me understand what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not feasible to know exactly what the issue is. But the first question is: are you _sure_ that the code does not proceed past the statement in question? The debugger has pretty good async/await support, but when execution moves from one thread to another, it's still possible for it to get lost. There's a huge difference between a question about why the debugger acts a particular way (which is what your question seems to be) and why the _code_ acts a particular way.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I would have supplied a reproducible example if I could, but the code gets complicated. I will likely have to 'flatten' my code out to see if I can make it work. Thanks for the comment. :-)

Comment: What do expect to achieve with that code? Could it be that you're accessing controls outside of the UI thread?

Comment: I will have a look to see if I leave the UI Thread. I may have to simplify the "find tooltip" tasks to achieve what i need.

Comment: `Task.Run` will push the function onto a background thread.  You need to make sure that anything that happens in `FindTooltip` that does anything with UI is appropriately marshaled onto the UI thread.  Look into the dispatcher which can help with this (since you're `Await`ing at the top level, the UI thread will be free to handle the update).